# custom.css loads with delay while bootstrap style shows for few seconds first

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, customization

I created custom.css to overwrite my bootstrap. It works but for a few seconds, it shows default bootstrap style first, and then loads custom one. Any ideas? Thanks!

The custom css goes after bootstrap btw:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://toert.github.io/Isolated-Bootstrap/versions/4.0.0-beta/iso_bootstrap4.0.0min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
```

Comment: I have 3 ideas in mind, hope some can help you.

1: Try to overwrite your: "bootstrap.css", with the css rules that you write, not creating a: "custom.css".

2: Add an: "!important", to your css rules in your: "custom.css"

3: Verify how are your organize the files in your: "head" tag.

Comment: thank you, tried all of them but still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

`<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://toert.github.io/Isolated-Bootstrap/versions/4.0.0-beta/iso_bootstrap4.0.0min.css">`

Try switching the places so that custom.css loads first ^^

Comment: Mmmm, weird. This is not a great solution but perhaps the style attribute with the stylings from custom.css will directly apply since it has higher priority.

Comment: Okay, I added style to the section with bootstrap directly in html file and now it works - it's showing only my custom style, not the bootstrap one. I know it's not the best practice to style directly in html but that was the only solution that worked in this case I guess

Comment: Yeah, but ey, we have to break the law and be bad sometimes to get certain things work, eh. xD